# Extra Python libraries on phone

Tags: python, symbian, s60, pys60

I have Python installed on my S60 phone...but I require some addtional libraries like pyaudio and lightblue to be installed on my phone...is there a way I can do this?
Also where are the Python libraries installed on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks those libraries will run on PyS60 if they are not designed for that platform.